# possible combination of a particular binary number

Tags: java, c

How to print all the possible combination of a particular binary number without repetitions in values using java/c

For Example:

Input:

```
110011111
```

Output:

```
100111111
111110011
111001111
111111100
```

etc..

Comment: Please select any one language.

Comment: and provide some code you tried and failed with. This is not a "do my homework site"

Comment: What? I don't understand

Comment: Suppose the number is `n` digits long, then there will be `2^n` different combinations. If `n` is small, you can use some nested loops. What have you tried so far?

Comment: this is an interview question and i really don't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: What is biggest possible decimal value? So why not count from 0 to max_val and the convert / print the binary representation.

Comment: It can be any length? e.g. 8-bit, 16-bit, etc?

Comment: just for the value given, bit size not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first way that came to mind. May be better or more efficient approaches.

1. Construct a binary tree. Root node has no value. Left is 0 and right
   is 1 (doesn't really matter which is which). Depth of the tree is
   number of bits plus 1 (to account for the root).
2. Do a full depth first traversal of the tree. Counting the number of
   1's (or 0's) for each traversal.
3. If the number of 1's (or 0's) matches the input then that traversal
   can be added to the answer set.

Comment: Of course this is almost a brute force method. You can make it much more efficient if you put some more thought into it. For example, you can actually do the counting as you construct the tree so that you don't have to construct the full tree and you actually end up with the full answer set when the tree construction completes (all branchs with the full depth). Of course, that is (a little) more complex than the basic solution but would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

for me, I will solve it as following (brute force),(not the perfect solution): http://ideone.com/d37KDK

```
#include <stdio.h>

void showbits(int n)
{
    int i,k,andmask;

    for(i=31;i>=0;i--)
    {
        andmask = 1 << i;
        k = n & andmask;

        k == 0 ? printf("0") : printf("1");
    }
    printf("\n");

}

int numberOfOnes (int num) {
    int count = 0;
    unsigned int u = (unsigned int)num;
    while (u != 0) {
        if ((u&1) == 1)
            count++;
        u >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{

    int n = 0b110011111;
    int n_num_of_ones = numberOfOnes(n);
    int max = 1 << 30;
    printf("max=%d\n" , max);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < max ; i++)
        if(numberOfOnes(i) == n_num_of_ones)
            showbits(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @SridharS : it takes a long time to finish, for me, I terminate it using CTRL + C .

Comment: yes it does but i only wanted the output for the particular problem . What should i do then.

Comment: try it with 'short' data type instead of 'int' .

Comment: I thought your interview was over? Don't tell me you are trying to submit an interview answer by getting it from Stackoverflow.